# Updating column values on specific Row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to update value from xt to xtt in 6th column, first row.

```
1    2    3   4    5  6

x    xx  xy   xz   x1 xt

y    yx  tt   cc  z3  xcc
```

Based on above data, I am getting range from worksheet. After getting the `Row` object, how do I update the Cell value in particular column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked, you can update a specific column using the method:

```
'Sheet.Cells(row, column) = value
' i.e.
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6) = "xtt"
```

If you only want to perform the update if it has a value of "xt", then obviously you'd need to check the contents before performing the update...  For example:

```
If (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6) = "xt") Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6) = "xtt"
End If
```

Comment: :I updated my question,After getting row object.I want to update cell value